# communicate or access a parent from another using c#

Tags: c#, parent

I seem to be have a great deal of trouble with a simple issue. Yes I'm new to c# but I try to learn what I can without jumping to post a question. In this case I just think I'm not asking the right question.

No code samples will help here because I'm talking about the basics ( implementation ). I have not really coded anything yet, just use the visual builder to create my windows forms and menus.

The issue I'm having is when I select a menu item (call it: set paths ) I want that list view on my main form to load from the path selected when I hit ok on form2. So I did a simple find folder dialog and I have my new path stored on form2 in a text box. When I hit ok on that form2 I want my listview form1 to populate. I know how to do all of this but I can not for the life of me access form1 from form2 or vice versa.

I tried making a call back function but I get that non-static variable cannot be referenced... error because my form1 is static, so I can't create any non static methods. I looked in to EventArgs but that just seems like an over kill for such a common request.

So what is the general way to do this?

Comment: In general, you'd display Form2 using ShowDialog(), then check that result for a DialogResult.OK back in Form1 (setting DialogResult to OK in Form2 when the "OK" button is clicked).  As RobertHavey explained, you'd use the reference to Form2 that you already have to access the desired value.  The missing ingredient is that you can't (by default) access the value stored in the TextBox on Form2.  You can "fix" this by setting the Modifiers() property of the TextBox to Public.  The preferred method, however, is to create a custom Property on Form2 to hold the value.

Comment: Perfect! DialogResult is exactly what I needed. I forgot about the returns on windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Robert's answer is correct as far as accessing members on another form. However, in general you should be storing the state of your application (call it the "model") *separately* from the state of your user interface (call it the "view"). This becomes very important as your application grows beyond one or two interactions. There are several philosophies or patterns about how to tie the two together (Google "model-view-controller" (MVC) and "model-view-viewmodel" (MVVM) for example), and if you really want to do this correctly I would recommend learning about those. My preference is for the MVVM approach, and you can do it fairly easily with Windows Forms even though it was designed with WPF applications in mind.

In .NET, the basic piece of code you should use to implement the connection between your viewmodel and your view is an interface called [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You create a class that implements this interface and sends notifications whenever a property changes, so for example for your path property you would create this class:

```
class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string path;
    public string Path
    {
        get { return path; }
        set {
            if (value != path)
            {
                path = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    // This event gets triggered whenever a property changes.
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    // This will cause the event to actually be triggered. It automatically determines the name of the property that triggered it using the [CallerMemberName] attribute - just a bit of .NET 4.5 sweetness. :)
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

It may seem like a lot of work, but now in your form1 you can create a new "ViewModel" instance, subscribe to the event, and then pass the instance to form2. form2 then simply updates the Path property on the viewmodel instance whenever the user selects a different path.

So, Form1 needs this code near the top:

```
private ViewModel viewmodel = new ViewModel();
```

And this goes in the Form1 constructor:

```
viewmodel.PropertyChanged += new EventHandler(OnPathChanged);
```

And when you create/show form2:

```
var form2 = new Form2(viewmodel); // Note, the viewmodel instance is being passed to the form2 constructor
form2.Show();
```

The form2 constructor then stores its own reference to the "viewmodel" instance, and sets the Path property whenever the path is changed by the user.

```
private ViewModel viewmodel;

public Form2(ViewModel viewmodel)
{
    this.viewmodel = viewmodel;
    ... // Other stuff to set up your controls etc. goes here
}

private void PathChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) // This may be named differently in your code; it's the event handler that gets called when the path changes
{
    // This will automatically notify the event handler in Form1! It's super-elegant and flexible.
    this.viewmodel.Path = txtPath.Text; // Assuming you have a textbox called txtPath
}
```

And finally the event handler in Form1:

```
private void OnPathChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var newPath = viewmodel.Path; // Get the updated path back from the viewmodel
    //TODO: Whatever you want to do when the path changes.
}
```

Here's a link to a really good MVVM intro using Windows Forms, it uses two forms like you have in your example. [MVVM (Model-View-ViewModel) Pattern For Windows Form Applications, using C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/364485/MVVM-Model-View-ViewModel-Patte)

Comment: I think this answers the question the best but DialogResult was what I really wanted ( my fault for the long winded explanation ).

Comment: No problem. Your explanation was fine! (Although a few code snippets would be good to include in a question like that, for example the class names & where you create/show form2 inside form1) I think it's helpful to see different approaches - the straightforward solution that you need right now, and the more elaborate one that you'll need later when your application grows.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to access something on another form, just hold a reference to it from your first form, like this:

```
form2 = new Form2();
form2.Show();
form2.WhateverYouWantToAccess
```

That said, if you just want to get a file path from the user, you want to use the [OpenFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Stream myStream = null;
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

    openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "c:\\" ;
    openFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*" ;
    openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2 ;
    openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true ;

    if(openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        try
        {
            if ((myStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
            {
                using (myStream)
                {
                    // Insert code to read the stream here.
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk. Original error: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No, that's not what Sean is asking about. He wants to know, in general, how to solve the problem of communicating between different forms. Though I agree this is a quick fix - just putting the OpenFileDialog call in Sean's "form1" - it doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: ok, but as I said that part I know how to do, its the access back to main form that is my issue. Thx for this though now I see how to handle errors.

Comment: @LarsKemmann *[sigh]* Fine, I'll put something in my answer to that effect.  But there's no way I'm going to recommend that someone create a custom form just to get a path.