# Where to create the class

Tags: c#, inheritance

I'm trying to model a production system with "facility" as Class and some subclasses down to "Activity". The facility has a name as only parameter (at the moment), and I'd like to create an instance of the class reading the name as an input from a textbox. Since "activity" is inherit the properties from it's "parent classes" I'll create an instance of the class "activity" and not it's parent.

The problem is that I don't know where to create the class and how to pass it so that when I add the first subclass "Workstation" I can edit the properties of the same "activity" I created earlier.

I don't really have any code to add at this point unfortunately, but please tell me if there's anything special you'd like to see and I'll try to add it to the post.

And by the way, it's in the shape of a WinForm application with a GUI I'm trying to do this.

Comment: It's very difficult to answer a question like this without *some* sort of context. You must know at least what type of app you are building? WinForms/Console/WPF etc.? Unless you provide more information, sadly, your question will probably end up closed.

Comment: Oh, sorry! It's a WinForm application in C# and what I'm trying to do in short is to create a structure of a factory layout, with a GUI to read the properties for each part (Name, number of machines or whatever).

Comment: Not everything should be modeled with inheritance. Is an "activity" as specific kind of "workstation" ? I don't think so. Use normal associations (i.e. references between objects).

Comment: Hmm, well the factory contains workstation that contains activities (like "assemble part 1") that contains sub-activities (like "get tool 1") and so forth.

Comment: @user2950764 what's the *real* question here then? Where to keep a reference to your model inside a WinForms app so it can be re-used? If so, again there isn't really much room for an answer without knowing the setup of your GUI.

Comment: What is your IDE? Usually, you create a class in a new .cs file.

Comment: James: Yes, that sounds like the question! Where shall I create the class so that I can get and set the information of it from all other part of the program?

Comment: @ThunderGr: I have created the class "structure" in a new .cs file, but I need to construct an instance of that class in order to fill it with information.

Comment: You define the object in the place you want to use it. That is, in another class' body or in a method or in the main function.

Comment: @ThunderGr: So if I create an instance of the object first thing in the main class, I can add and edit information in that instance in every other part of the problem (like in the Form GUI)?

Comment: if you declare it as `public`, yes.

Comment: See the link to the similar answer that I posted; that will give you details about where to create instances of the objects so that you can display it in the GUI wherever you need, and still update it elsewhere (e.g., from a live data source).

Comment: Just making a class `public` isn't going to do it - you'll need to have a **reference** to your object in every part of the user interface. Again, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21861327/communicate-or-access-a-parent-from-another-using-c-sharp/21862059#21862059 for a full example with proper design.

Comment: @LarsKemmann Making the *object* public, Lars. It will do it.

Comment: Ah, okay. I misread that, you're right. :)

Comment: @ThunderGr: I'm sorry but I really don't get it. According to Visual Studio, I can't create an instance of the parent-class in my main class/the class "program" since those are static as default? Should I put the constructor (public Activity myActivity = new Activity(); ) inside the Form class? And how do I set the values in my instance of the class from the textboxes?

Comment: static public MyClass anObject=new MyClass();

Comment: If you want an instance of it accessible from everywhere, you need to do that. If not, you have to play with references, as Lars said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple things to note here. First, you'll want to use the [Composite pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/composite-pattern.html) to encapsulate the relationships between your classes. (For those who don't understand the OP's type hierarchy, it does make perfect sense in a factory context. There are many activities going on, which can be grouped into workstations and at a higher level into facilities.)

So, you should probably have a base `Activity` class (that supports the Composite pattern by exposing a collection of child activities), and then your "levels" (like `Facility` and `Workstation`) will inherit from `Activity`. Each of these classes will have unique properties.

The following classes should be created in their respective files, e.g. `Activity.cs`, `Factory.cs`, `Workstation.cs`:

```
class Activity
{
    // An attribute that every Activity may need: a displayable name.
    // This might be useful if you have a TreeView, e.g., showing all the activities.
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    // Every Activity could have child activities - this is the Composite pattern.
    // You can loop through these to navigate through the hierarchy of your data.
    // (This is often done using recursion; see example below with GetAllWorkstations().)
    public List<Activity> ChildActivities { get; private set; }

    public Activity()
    {
        ChildActivities = new List<Activity>();
    }

    public override string ToString() { return Name; }
}

class Factory : Activity
{
    public string City { get; private set; }
    public string Address { get; private set; }
}

class Workstation : Activity
{
    public string WorkstationNumber { get; private set; }
}
```

The responsibility of **loading** your model then has to be handled somewhere. A good place to do it is in your main form. For example, you might write code like this:

```
class MainForm : Form
{
    private readonly List<Factory> topLevelFactoryActivities;

    public MainForm()
    {
        // ... other code

        topLevelFactoryActivities = LoadTopLevelFactoryActivities();
    }

    private IEnumerable<Factory> LoadTopLevelFactoryActivities()
    {
        var factories = new List<Factory>();

        // TODO: Load the factories, e.g. from a database or a file.
        // You can load all the child objects for each factory here as well,
        // or wait until later ("lazy-loading") if you want to.

        // NOTE: If this becomes complex, you can move the LoadTopLevelFactoryActivities()
        // method to its own class, which then becomes your "data access layer" (DAL).

        return factories;
    }
}
```

Now, if you want to find all the workstations that are part of a particular factory, you would write a method like the following on the `Factory` class:

```
class Factory : Activity
{
    // ... other code

    public IEnumerable<Workstation> GetAllWorkstations()
    {
        return GetWorkstationsRecursive(this);
    }

    private IEnumerable<Workstation> WorkstationsIn(Activity parentActivity)
    {
        foreach (var workstation in parentActivity.ChildActivities.OfType<Workstation>)
        {
            // Uses a C# feature called 'iterators' - really powerful!
            yield return workstation;
        }
        foreach (var childActivity in parentActivity.ChildActivities)
        {
            // Using recursion to go down the hierarchy
            foreach (var workstation in WorkstationsIn(childActivity))
            {
                yield return workstation;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You would call it like so, e.g. in your main form:

```
class MainForm : Form
{
    // ... other code

    public MainForm()
    {
        // ... other code

        // Assume this is assigned to the factory that you want to get all the workstations for
        Factory myFactory;
        var workstations = myFactory.GetAllWorkstations();
        // Now you can use 'workstations' as the items source for a list, for example.
    }
}
```

As an example use case, you might want to show a second form (that belongs to the main form) which shows a list of all the workstations. (In practice you probably shouldn't create too many windows; prefer building a nonoverlapping layout. But just to show how you might pass the model instances around...)

```
class WorkstationListForm : Form
{
    private IEnumerable<Workstation> workstations;

    public WorkstationListForm(IEnumerable<Workstation> workstations)
    {
        this.workstations = workstations;
        //TODO: You can now use 'workstations' as the ItemsSource of a list view in this form.
    }
}
```

You could, of course, make `topLevelFactoryActivities` **public** on your `MainForm` and pass the variable `this` of the `MainForm` to the `WorkstationListForm` constructor instead. Then you could access the member on `MainForm` like this:

```
public WorkstationListForm(MainForm mainForm)
{
    var topLevelFactoryActivities = mainForm.topLevelFactoryActivities;
    // Now WorkstationListForm has full access to all the data on MainForm. This may or
    // may not be helpful (it's usually best to minimize sharing and public fields).
}
```

Second, you'll want to use a proper separation between your view (user interface code/classes) and your model (the Activity hierarchy).

Third, if there's going to be any kind of live data being pushed to the user interface then you'll need a databinding mechanism to automatically update the view whenever the model changes.

In general, #2 & #3 are popularly addressed via the Model-View-ViewModel pattern. There is an excellent [tutorial here for building an MVVM app using WinForms/C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/364485/MVVM-Model-View-ViewModel-Patte).

That should get you started, at least. Also see an answer to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21861327/communicate-or-access-a-parent-from-another-using-c-sharp/21862059#21862059). (Sorry about promoting my own answer, but I don't want to type out the whole example twice. Please forgive me. :))

Comment: Many thanks Lars! I used the opposite "approach" where the facility is the parent, the workstation the child to the facility and the activity is the child to the facility, but I assume that's wrong? And when I create an instance, I should create an instance of the last "grandchildren" since that one have all the features of it's parents, right? I can't get too much of the MVWM thing unfortunately, but the INotifyPropertyChanged might be very useful!

Comment: Don't worry about doing a full-blown MVVM design right away. :) But yes, `INotifyPropertyChanged` will help you a lot with this! I'm still trying to understand what you mean by "have all the features of its parents". Do you mean you did something like `class Workstation : Facility`? Yes, that would be wrong - a Workstation is not a **kind** of Facility, but rather a Facility **contains** one or more Workstations. That's why the `List<Activity> ChildActivities` is there.

Comment: By "have all the feature of it's parent" I mean that the facility will have a location (say a city). The parent to the facility, the factory, will of course also have a location that is the same as the facility, given that a facility is a group of factories at roughly the same place.

Comment: Sure, that makes sense. But inheritance is not the best way to solve this problem - you should use inheritance only for sharing **behaviors** with subclasses. I'll update the example code with some pointers for how to address what you're looking to do.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you mean by behaviors, aren't say "facilityName" a behavior for the facility? And the part of "Factory myFactory", where do you put that piece of code? In the main program? I'm still a little confused from the comments to the original post, shall I construct the class in main and make it public or not?

Comment: No, `facilityName` isn't a behavior - it's **data** that the Facility owns. From a modeling perspective, a class should only contain data that it **owns** exclusively (so it can control how that data is updated, e.g. using a database). I'll add a few explanations more about where the pieces of the code go.

Comment: You don't need to make the Factory instance variable public in your main form. You can just pass it (by reference) wherever it is needed - and this solves the problem of having to worry about static vs. instance variables.