# Closing multiple windows form with single click

Tags: c#

I want to close two forms at the same time. I have one main form that starts with program. when user click button, the main form will hide and other form will pop up. on the second form if user click "back to main " button, it should hide second form and show main form. But the problem is if user tries to close the second form it should close the main form as well. How can i close the main form as well

Comment: Invoke its `Close` method :)

Comment: where can i use form.close() methods ?

Comment: Take a look at this question; it has detailed answers on how to communicate properly between two forms, including how to send data between them in case you need to do that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21861327/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just use the Application.Exit() for what is requested by this thread.

```
Application.Exit();
```

UPDATE: corrected

I had said this will not call the form closing events but in documentation it does actually call it here is a link to the documentation

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157894(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: That will provide a short-term solution, however you don't know if it would address the OP's long-term needs.

Comment: He never said anything about long term I am just answering his question as he stated it...

Comment: I can't argue the obvious, but you're not helping the OP to really learn either. :)

Comment: The documentation of [Application.Exit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157894(v=vs.110).aspx) says it will cause the FormClosing event to be raised. Application.Exit is completely valid to use in this situation, with the understanding of the FormClosing event.

Answer (score 2):

It was better if you specified what codes you wrote for going back to main form, so I could help you by changing your codes. But now because I don't know how you did it, I have to write codes for both of those tasks.
It can be possible using a Boolean variable to do what you want. Follow bellow codes:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
//"Click" event of the button that should opens the second form:
private void goToSecondForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 f2 = new Form2(); //Or you can write it out of this method.
        this.Hide(); //Hides the main form.
        f2.ShowDialog(); // Shows the second form.
        this.Show(); // Shows the main form again, after closing the second form using your own button.
    }
}


public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    bool selfClose = false; //False shows that user closed the second form by default button and true shows that user closed it by your own button.
    //"Click" event of the button that should closes just the second form and returns user to the main form:
    private void ownCloseButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        selfClose = true; //Means user clicked on your own button.
        this.Close(); //So the program closes the second form and runs f2_FormClosed method, but because selfClose became true here, happened nothing there and program will go back to goToSecondForm_Click method in the main form and will run this.Show() .
    }
//"FormClosed" event of the second form :
//Whether user clicked on your own button or on the default one, this method will run.
private void f2_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!selfClose) //It means user didn't click on your own button and both of forms must be closed .
            Application.Exit(); //So the program closes all of forms (actually closes the program) and couldn't access to any other commands (including this.Show() in goToSecondForm_Click method).
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Reyhaneh SH. Found my way now.

Comment: please mark this answer as the correct answer by clicking on the green checkmark beside it.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you need to somehow call `.Close()` on the main form when your child form is closed. However, as you've pointed out, you don't have a reference to the main form automatically in your child form! That leaves you with a few options.

**1. Exit the application immediately.**
This is done by calling `Application.Exit();` in your child form's "back to main" button's click event handler. It will immediately close all forms, which might simply be what you want.

```
// .. ChildForm code ..
void OnBackToMainClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Application.Exit();
}
```

**2. Pass a reference to the main form to the child form.**
This is probably the most common way to solve this problem in general. When you create your child form in your main form, you'll need to pass a reference as follows:

```
// .. MainForm code ..
void OnGoToChildForm(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var childForm = new ChildForm(this);
    childForm.Show();
}
```

```
// .. ChildForm code ..
private MainForm mainForm; // This is where the child form will keep a reference to
                           // the main form that you can use later

public ChildForm(MainForm mainForm)
{
    // This is the child form's constructor that we called above,
    // and it's where we'll save the reference to the main form
    this.mainForm = mainForm;
}

// This also needs to be the event handler for the close event
void OnBackToMainClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
    mainForm.Close();
}
```

**3. Add an event handler on the child form's `FormClosed` event.** This is a safe way to solve the problem if you are concerned about keeping your main application logic under the control of the main form. It's similar to the solution suggested by Lamloumi above, but it's all done in the main form's code.

```
// .. MainForm code ..
void OnGoToChildForm(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var childForm = new ChildForm(this);
    childForm.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(SecondForm_FormClosed);
    childForm.Show();
}

void SecondForm_FormClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Perform any final cleanup logic here.
    this.Close();
}
```

Comment: Let me clarify here. When I am in second form, the main form is hidden. But if user hit " X" on the second form I also want main form to be closed.

Comment: This code does exactly that. In fact all three options do exactly that! :) Have you tried any of them, @want2learn? (I did have a bug in the second option that I've fixed now.)

Answer (score -1):

Normally , in the Home form you have some ting like this :

```
  SecondForm second= new SecondForm ();
       second.Show();
       this.Hide();
```

In the SecondForm you must ovveride the event of closure like this :

```
   public class SecondForm :Form{

            public SecondForm()
                  {
                 InitializeComponent();
                 this.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(SecondForm_FormClosed);
                   }

                void SecondForm_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
                {
                Application.Exit();
                 }
}
```

To be sure that your application is closed after you close the form. because the Home from is still active and hidden if you don't.

Comment: 1) What is `SecondForm_FormClosed` ? 2) `FormClosedEventHandler` is a delegate not a method name. Is that enough..... Next time, try to compile your code before posting.... BTW: You don't override an event, you attach to it.....

Comment: I agree, there's no reason to downvote this. However, @LamloumiAfif, perhaps you should alert the OP to the fact that this approach will cause a hard stop on your program, i.e. the Main form will have no chance to do anything (such as save a file, etc.) before the program exits.

Comment: @LarsKemmann Maybe the OP wants effectively forcing the closure of the form and he don't care about the  possible risks

Comment: Lamloumi, in that case it's perfectly justified to use this approach. :) @L.B, I also downvoted an answer, but I also provided an explanation of my reasons. I can understand the frustration over being downvoted without any reasoning given. Don't assume people know what you're thinking.

Comment: @L.B I don't understand why u are so offensive !!!!!!!!, I'm simply asking about your reasons , relax man :)

Answer (score -1):

```
Form1 _FirstForm = New Form1();
Form2 _SecondForm = New Form2();
MainForm _MainForm = new MainForm();

_FirstForm.Close();
_SecondForm.Close();
_MainForm.Show();
```

Comment: This does not address how the OP would actually call the `.Close()` method(s) during, say, a "Back to main" button handler as described in the question. The OP needs to know how to get a reference to the main form into the second form.

Answer (score -1):

use this in Form2

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form1.FromHandle(this.Handle);
        }
```

There Handle are the same now ;
hope this work.

Comment: You know what to do in first Form1 i did not included

Comment: changing the handle of the form is never suggested. harmful for repainting events.

Comment: I know that but it will not effect on exit . how wanna use paint after exit.